# Syntax when comment a table in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I want to comment a table in SQL (Oracle) and add an URL into this comment:

```
comment on table A is 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
```

But it return an error : Unknown command.

What is the correct syntax, how to escape special char?

Comment: Please post your real case. `"Ok, there's a "#" at the end of my URL."`. Your case is not reproducible. **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a2b0f9ca4c03b394b0b5e5b38e65bd76)**

Comment: The syntax is correct. What is the **exact** error you get?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I discovered DBfiddle today !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply

```
comment on table "HR"."A"  is 'https://stackoverflow.com/#'
```

And since you tagged SQL Developer, here is that, in SQL Developer.

[image]

Which now appears here:

[image]

You can find the [Docs for that here.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/COMMENT.html#GUID-65F447C4-6914-4823-9691-F15D52DB74D7)